# Getting distinct result without using the DISTINCT clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following code, I am able to get the result I desire by using DISTINCT but is there a way to get the same result without using DISTINCT?

```
SELECT S.name, COUNT(DISTINCT R.peopleID) AS numathletes
FROM Sports S
JOIN Results R ON S.ID = R.sportID
WHERE R.result >= S.record
GROUP BY S.name;
```

as for the tables i'm using:
Table S has ID, name, record
Table R has peopleID, competitionID, sportID, result

Comment: I dunno.  Depends on your data.  I mean, there are likely to be other ways to formulate the query, but the query would be more complicated, perhaps.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function. Remove those redundant parentheses and simply write `COUNT(DISTINCT R.peopleID) AS numathletes` to make code clearer!

Comment: Probably but for what reason? Why substitute a more complicated, probably slower bit of code?

Comment: @Nick Just out of curiosity, my data science professor was talking about how there can be multiple ways to write a query, I asked this knowing well that DISTINCT was likely the ideal path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Here is one variant

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS numathletes
FROM
(
    SELECT S.name, R.peopleID
    FROM 
        Sports S
        JOIN Results R ON S.ID = R.sportID
    WHERE R.result >= S.record
    GROUP BY S.name, R.peopleID
) AS T
GROUP BY name;
```

It is a more verbose variant which shows clearly how the calculations are done.

You should try and check with your data and hardware which variant is faster.
Quite likely that they will perform the same.